# Differentiating between two integers in a string

Tags: c#, string, primes

I have a problem I've been working on where I want to identify all integers within a given string that are prime (numbers that are divisible only by 1 and itself).

The logic I have written for this problem is done and correct, but in debugging and testing the code I came upon an interesting scenario.

Say I have the following string
`This 15 i2s the45best str7ng 1n th3 w0r17ld`

Now when the above string was ran through my program it determined that the prime numbers in the string were `5, 2, 5, 7, 3, 7`, which is correct. However, what if I wanted my program to check to see if `15` was prime instead of individually checking if `1` is a prime and then checking to see if `5` is a prime, or if I want to check the primality of `45` instead of `4` and `5` individually?

I'd like to also extend this question to numbers that are, in general, greater than 1 digit long.

Below is the code I have for accomplishing what I've described:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sentence = "This 15 i2s the45best str7ng 1n th3 w0r17ld";
    string primes = string.Empty;
    foreach(char c in sentence)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            if (isPrime(c - 48))
            {
                primes += c;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(primes.Length > 0 ? $"The prime numbers in\n\n\t{sentence}\n\nare {string.Join<char>(", ", primes)}" : $"There exist no primes in\n\n\t{sentence}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool isPrime(int number)
{
    if(number == 3 || number == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(number % 2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 3; i < (int)Math.Sqrt(number); i++)
    {
        if(number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Obviously, you have to write some code that treats a sequence of digits as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the problem in two smaller ones:

```
  1. Extract all integers from the string
  2. Check integer value if it is a prime one
```

First subtask can be solved with help of *regular expressions*:

```
  // IEnumerable<int> - we assume that all integers within the string are small enough.
  // If we can face an arbitrary integer sample12345678901234567890123456
  // BigInteger (instead of int) is the solution
  private static IEnumerable<int> ExtractIntValues(string source) {
    return Regex
     .Matches(source, "[0-9]+")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value));
  }
```

Second subtask can be implemented as (your code slightly optimized)

```
  private static bool isPrime(int number) {
    if (number <= 1) // 0 and 1 are not primes
      return false;
    if (number % 2 == 0)
      return n == 2;

    int n = (int) (Math.Sqrt(number) + 0.5);

    for (int i = 3; i < n; i += 2) // we have to check odd divisors only
      if (number % i == 0)
        return false;

    return true;   
  }
```

Finally:

```
  string sentence = "This 15 i2s the45best str7ng 1n th3 w0r17ld";

  int[] primes = ExtractIntValues(sentence)
    .Where(number => IsPrime(number))
    .ToArray(); 

  Console.WriteLine($"string '{sentence}' contains {primes.Length} prime numbers: {string.Join(", ", primes)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sentence = "This 15 i2s the45best str7ng 1n th3 w0r17ld";
    List<int> primes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
    {  
        // iterate 'sentence' as long as the neighbour of the current character is a valid digit, then add these digits up to a string
        string nStr = string.Empty;
        while (char.IsDigit(sentence[i]))
        {
            nStr += sentence[i];
            i++;
        }

        // if a number was detected and it is a prime number, add it to our list
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nStr))
        {
            int n = int.Parse(nStr);
            if (IsPrime(n))
                primes.Add(n);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(primes.Count > 0 ? $"The prime numbers in\n\n\t{sentence}\n\nare {string.Join(", ", primes.ToArray())}" : $"There exist no primes in\n\n\t{sentence}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    if (number == 1)
        return false;
    if (number == 2)
        return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    var boundary = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));

    for (int i = 3; i <= boundary; i += 2)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Please note:**
I took another `IsPrime` method, because there was something wrong with yours. Check it out here: [IsPrime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743192/check-if-number-is-prime-number)

Comment: `(int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));` is *dangerous* code: what if `Math.Sqrt` for given `p * p` returns not `p`, but `p - ε`? Say, `Sqrt(25) == 4.9999999999999997` on some platform, FPU etc?