# IEEE double such that sqrt(x*x) ≠ x

Tags: floating-point, double, ieee-754, square-root

Does there exist an IEEE double `x>0` such that `sqrt(x*x) ≠ x`, under the condition that the computation `x*x` does not overflow or underflow to `Inf`, `0`, or a denormal number?

This is given that `sqrt` returns the nearest representable result, and so does `x*x` (both as mandated by the IEEE standard, "square root operation be calculated as if in infinite precision, and then rounded to one of the two nearest floating-point numbers of the specified precision that surround the infinitely precise result").

Under the assumption that if such doubles would exist, then there are probably examples close to 1, I wrote a program to find these counterexamples, and it failed to find any between `1.0` and `1.0000004780981346`.

The previous similar question [perfect squares and floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151740/sqrt-perfect-squares-and-floating-point-errors) answers the question in the negative for situations where the computation of `x*x` does *not* involve rounding. That answer is not sufficient for this question because it may be possible for `x*x` to involve rounding in one direction, then `sqrt(x*x)` to involve rounding in the *same* direction, thus producing an answer that is not exactly `x`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sylvie Boldo has [formally proved](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01148409/document) that a floating-point number satisfying the conditions in your question does not exist.

Quoting the abstract of the article:

> Floating-point experts know that mathematical formulas may fail or
>   give imprecise results when implemented in floating-point arithmetic.
>   This article describes an example where, surprisingly, it is
>   absolutely not the case. Indeed, using radix 2 and an unbounded
>   exponent range, the computation of the square root of the square of a
>   floating-point number a is exactly |a|. A consequence is the fact that
>   the floating-point computation of a/ sqrt (a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>) is always in the
>   interval [−1, 1]. This removes the need for a test when calling an
>   arccos or an arcsin on this value. For more guarantees, this property
>   was formally checked using the Coq proof assistant and the Flocq
>   library. The conclusion will give hints on what happens without
>   assumptions and in other radices, where the behavior is very
>   different.

“using radix 2” was likely implicit in your question (although the IEEE has also standardized decimal floating-point number formats and operations), and “an unbounded exponent range” is equivalent to your “no overflow or underflow” restriction.

A reason making the property possible at all is that `x*x` “expands” (the interval [1,2] is mapped to [1,4], for instance) in a way such that, when there is no overflow or underflow, the rounding that can happen for `*` is benign and `x` is still the closest representable floating-point number to the real square root of the floating-point product `x*x`. This hand-wavy argument does not constitute a proof, so it's a good thing that the article linked above contains one.

Comment: I believe this result, but still find it extremely surprising.

Comment: This paper shows that √(x²) has no error.  What's the largest error in (√x)² for a single-precision number?  For a double?

Comment: @MikeStay you should ask that as a question if you expect an answer