# NumPy complex128 division inconsistent with float64 division

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing complex division in a context where numerical precision really matters. I find that dividing two complex128 numbers with no imaginary part gives a different result beyond 15 decimal digits that dividing the same two numbers as float64.

```py
a = np.float64(1.501)
b = np.float64(1.337)

print('{:.20f}'.format(a / b))
# 1.12266267763649962852

a_com = np.complex128(1.501)
b_com = np.complex128(1.337)

print('{:.20f}'.format((a_com / b_com).real))
# 1.12266267763649940647
```

I have a C++ reference implementation where complex division agrees with NumPy float division beyond 15 decimal digits. I'd like to use NumPy complex division with the same precision. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import numpy as np

def compl_div(A,B):
    A,B = np.asarray(A),np.asarray(B)
    Ba = np.abs(B)[...,None]
    A = (A[...,None].view(float)/Ba).view(complex)[...,0]
    B = (B.conj()[...,None].view(float)/Ba).view(complex)[...,0]
    return A*B

a = np.random.randn(10000)
b = np.random.randn(10000)
A = a.astype(complex)
B = b.astype(complex)

print((compl_div(A,B)==a/b).all())

print((np.sqrt(b*b)==np.abs(b)).all())

ac = a.view(complex)
bc = b.view(complex)

print(np.allclose(compl_div(ac,bc),ac/bc))
```

Sample run:

```
True    # complex without imag exactly equal float
True    # reason it works
True    # for nonzeron imag part do we actually get complex division
```

Explanation:

Let us write `///` for complex by float division `(x+iy)///r = x/r + iy/r`

numpy seems to implement complex division `A/B` as `A*(1/B)` (`1/B` can be computed as `B.conj()///(B.conj()*B)`), indeed A/B appears to always equal `a*(1/b)`

We do instead `(A///abs(B)) * (B.conj()///abs(B))` as `abs(B)^2 = B*B.conj()` this is mathematically, but not numerically, equivalent.

Now, if we had `abs(B) == abs(b)` then `A///abs(B) = a/abs(b)` and `B///abs(B) = sign(b)` and we could see that `compl_div(A,B)` indeed gives back exactly `a/b`.

As `abs(x+iy) = sqrt(x^2+y^2)` we need to show `sqrt(b*b) = abs(b)`. This is [provably true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41656438/7207392) unless there is over or underflow in the square or the square is denormal or the implementation does not conform to IEEE.