# Why does webassembly have a square root opcode?

Tags: webassembly, ieee-754

Webassembly offers only one of the more advanced floating point operations: the square root.

It doesn't have any of the others typically implemented in CPUs, such as powers and trigonometric functions, and this rationale is explained in the official FAQ:

> WebAssembly doesn’t include its own math functions like sin, cos, exp,
> pow, and so on. WebAssembly’s strategy for such functions is to allow
> them to be implemented as library routines in WebAssembly itself (note
> that x86’s sin and cos instructions are slow and imprecise and are
> generally avoided these days anyway). Users wishing to use faster and
> less precise math functions on WebAssembly can simply select a math
> library implementation which does so.

That begs the question if there's something special about square roots that justify to make an exception for it. It's useful for distance calculation, but does that come up that much more often that other kinds of powers or the exponential? Is it particularly fast on CPUs and they wanted to exploit that?

If we make two buckets of functions,

1. the first being addition, multiplication, division and remainder and
2. the second being powers, trigonometrics and their inversions

then why did they put square root in the first?

EDIT: I just realized that sqrt is special in that an approximation can be found by shifting the exponent one to the right. The exact result still requires finding the square root of the mantissa though, and that's still an interative process. But maybe this head start makes sqrt nice enough to warrant inclusion in IEEE's required operations as Olsonist noted.

There's also the property that `sqrt(x*x)=x` for all `x` for which `x*x` isn't over- or underflowing, which is unusual for operations that can involve rounding ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656528/870815)).

Comment: Square root is a simpler function than sine, cosine, e^x, and others. It is fairly readily calculated, and we have complete proofs about how to calculate it accurately. The others are harder, and we do not have complete proofs (about various aspects; it is complicated).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, since (x + x/2)^2 = 9/4*x^2 you can do a binary search to get an integer square root that takes log of the number of mantissa bits cycles and uses only shifting and summation (no multiplication). The exponent part is even easier as I already pointed out in the edit. Maybe I'm missing something, but that seems easier. I doubt sine can be calculated this fast with just shifting and adding.

Answer (score 5):

*IEEE 754-2008* is a requirement for WebAssembly and *sqrt* is a requirement for *IEEE 754-2008* while *sin*, *cos*, ... are not requirements for *IEEE 754-2008*. They are [recommended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) but not required.

Comment: Interesting, but that moves the same question to IEEE 754. What's so special about sqrt?

Comment: Division is also req'd in 754. sqrt and division are close enough cousins so that if a floating point implementation is going to do division, it's very little extra work to do sqrt.